# How can i get the sentence before special character (like :) by Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to get the sentence before ":" character from the full sentence.

ex. I have "This message will self destruct: Ruby is fun "

I only need "This message will self destruct"

this is my method

```
def destroy_message(sentence)
    check_list = /[^:]/
    sentence_list = /^([a-zA-z\s]+) \:/

    if sentence =~ check_list
        puts "have :"
        firstConsonant = sentence.match(sentence_list)
        puts firstConsonant
    else
        puts "Not have :"
    end
end

destroy_message("This message will self destruct: Ruby is fun ")
```

But i got nothing from puts firstConsonant.
How can i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: [Like this?](https://repl.it/BdNN)

Comment: Could not use `"This message will self destruct: Ruby is fun".split(':')[0]` => `"This message will self destruct"`

Answer (score 4):

I would just `split` the string at the `:` and use the first part. That is probably faster that using the complex regexp engine.

```
string = "This message will self destruct: Ruby is fun "

string.split(':').first
#=> "This message will self destruct"
```

Comment: You can improve the performance by passing `2` as the second argument to `split`.

Comment: You could also utilize `string.lazy.split(":").first`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ruby.rb
def destroy_message(sentence)
  result, * = sentence.split(':')
  unless result == "" # in case ":sentence_case"
    puts "#{result}"
  else
    puts "Not have :"
  end
end
destroy_message("This message will self destruct: Ruby is fun ")
```

Answer (score 0):

spickermann's answer will work, but besides that, there is a method `String#partition` specifically for doing this kind of thing (and also might be slightly faster).

```
s, * = "This message will self destruct: Ruby is fun ".partition(":")
s # => "This message will self destruct"
```

Answer (score -1):

> I got nothing from `puts firstConsonant`. How can I fix it?

You could use [#Scan Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan)

```
def destroy_message(sentence)
  if sentence.scan(/^[^:]+/)
    puts "have :"
    firstConsonant = sentence.scan(/^[^:]+/)
    puts firstConsonant[0]
  else
    puts "Not have :"
  end
end

destroy_message("This message will self destruct: Ruby is fun")
```

**Output**

```
 => have :
    This message will self destruct
```

---

Explanation about the Regex That used

- `^` asserts that we are at the start of a line.
- `[^...]` Negated character class which matches any character but not the one present inside that particular character class.
- `+` after the char class would repeat the char class one or more times.

Comment: How is newline relevant? Although this may work, it is significantly slow, compared to other methods posted so far. When a more complex answer is posted, usually that is for logical clarity or for performance, but from this answer, there is nothing to gain.

Comment: @sawa I agreed, But as the Question is about the writing own methods rather than using rubies built-in method, Also the Person who asked the question wants the know the problem with given Code.